# Loop that writes a number vertically

Tags: java

I'm trying to take the number 1234 and write it as:
1
2
3
4
My code has it displayed as:
4
3
2
1
Here is my code:

```
   public static void verticalLoop(int num )
    {
      while(num != 0)
      {
         System.out.println(num % 10);
         num = num / 10;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively.  Keep calling the method until a single digit is reached.  Then, return, unwinding the stack and printing the last digit.

```
verticalLoop(num);

public static void  verticalLoop(int num) {
   if (num > 9) {
        verticalLoop(num/10);
   }
   System.out.println(num%10);
}
```

Here are two other solutions which one might consider less advanced.

Store the digits in an array and print them in reverse order

- allocate an array of 10 (max digits for an int)
- iterate saving the digits as before, placing them in the array
- then using the one less than the value of `i`, iterate thru the array printing the digits.

```
public static void verticalLoop(int num) {
    // max digits for an int
    int[] digits = new int[10]; 
    int i = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        digits[i++] = num%10;
        num/=10;
    }
    for (int k = i-1; k >=0 ; k--) {
        System.out.println(digits[k]);
    }
}
```

This requires a little math. A logarithm is just an exponent. So raising `10` to the `log10(n)` simply gives you `n`. But the `int` of `log10(n)` gives you the number of digits less 1 in `n`.  So `(int)Math.log10(n)` gives you the `largest` power of `10` that won't yield `0` upon division.

- divide by the largest power of 10
- print the digit using `%`
- adjust the power to the next lower one by dividing by 10.
- continue until the divisor reaches 0.

```
public static void verticalLoop(int num) {
    int maxPower10 = (int)Math.pow(10,(int)Math.log10(num));
    while (maxPower10 > 0) {
        System.out.println((num/maxPower10) % 10);
        maxPower10/=10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very neat solution!

Comment: So for the assignment, we are supposed to do a recursion one as well. I did the recursion I just don't understand for the loop how do we flip 4321 to 1234. There have been plenty of good suggestions from everyone. Thank you very much for this suggestion!

Comment: I just provide a few more for your consideration.  If you have any questions, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the number to a string:

```
String s = Integer.toString(num);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
    }
```

Comment: My answer that returns has to be an int. Thanks for helping!